# Websockets don't work in all browsers

Tags: support, stack-overflow, google-chrome, web-sockets

<sup>Not sure where to ask this better</sup>

But at work I have new websockets stackoverflow implementation with smooth loading of all updates working well.

This is how it looks like in Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m at work:

[image]

but this is how it looks at the same Chrome version at home:

[image]

Any ideas what could cause that? I really like this new feature and lack of it at home makes me sad panda :-(

A bit more details: at home I have 2 laptops, both with very similar set of software (the same windows, the same antivirus (Kaspersky)). And both behave in similar way. Was thinking about router issues, but it is just a hardware router DLink with NAT

Comment: Here's a test url for web sockets:  http://www.websocket.org/echo.html  are you able to get connected using this?

Comment: @Geoff Dalgas: hmmmm... At work it works, and at home it returns "disconnected" for non-secure, whereas for secure works as expected :-S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a decent test page for web sockets:  http://websocketstest.com/

My guess is that you're being blocked by Kaspersky - see:  [Firewall blocks websocket](https://superuser.com/questions/423163/firewall-blocks-websocket)

Comment: I tried to turn off the protection but probably even when it states it is turned off - it still does something. Will check it in details this evening, thanks

Comment: Well, it's not even near SO issue, so I re-asked the question with more details at http://superuser.com/questions/423137/cannot-get-websockets-worked. Thanks